# Syntax error in MS Access Query?

Tags: sql, winforms, ms-access

I combined 7 columns into single column that is all address into a single column. Initially Location, City, State & Country are stored code its display value in that corresponding tables. So I joined all in this query below.

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerId, ContactPerson, 

((BFlatNo +','+ BPremises +','+ BStreet +','+ BArea) + ',' +
(select LocationName from Location where LocationId = Customer.Location) + ',' +
(select CityName from City where CityId = Customer.City) + ',' +
(select StateName from State where StateId = Customer.State) + ',' +
(select CountryName from Country where CountryId = Customer.Country) + ',' + 
(BMobileNumber) ) AS BillingAddress, 

((DFlatNo +','+ DPremises +','+ DStreet +','+ DArea) + ',' +
 (select LocationName from Location where LocationId = Customer.Location) + ',' +
 (select CityName from City where CityId = Customer.City) + ',' +
 (select StateName from State where StateId = Customer.State) + ',' +
 (select CountryName from Country where CountryId = Customer.Country) + ',' + 
(DPhone) ) AS DeliveryAddress

FROM Customer
WHERE Customer.CustomerId = 11;
```

While previewing Datasheet view in MS Access it asking for *Customer.Location*, *Customer.City*, *Customer.State* & *Customer.Country* then it showing result for CustomerId=11

[image]

I need to display Customer details when I click Datasheet View. 
Actually in Customer table Location its fieldname is BLocation, City is BCity, State is BState & Country is BCountry but If I give `Select LocationName from Location where LocationId=Customer.BLocation` it showning syntax error.

Help me how to solve this ?

Comment: Too many subqueries.  Use JOINs instead.  Start with the visual query designer, and work your way up to actual, hand-written queries.

Comment: I'd even consider creating a function in VBA that builds the full address when passed the 7 text elements of an address. It's not especially fast but I've found it easier to maintain and handle blanks than creating a really messy expression in the SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you guys This code working fine

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerId, ContactPerson,

((BFlatNo +','+ BPremises +','+ BStreet +','+ BArea)+','+
(select LocationName from Location where LocationId=Customer.BLocation)+','+
(select CityName from City where CityId=Customer.BCity)+','+
(select StateName from State where StateId=Customer.BState)+','+
(select CountryName from Country where CountryId=Customer.BCountry)+','+ (BMobileNumber)) AS BillingAddress,

((DFlatNo +','+ DPremises +','+ DStreet +','+ DArea)+','+
(select LocationName from Location where LocationId=Customer.DLocateion)+','+
(select CityName from City where CityId=Customer.DCity)+','+
(select StateName from State where StateId=Customer.DState)+','+
(select CountryName from Country where CountryId=Customer.DCountry)+','+ (DPhone)) AS DeliveryAddress

FROM Customer;
```